# Angular 4 Web Application to Ionic 3 App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Okay, so I have a working angular 4 web application that uses NodeJS as backend and MongoDB as a database. I know that Ionic 3 is based of Angular 4, and that is the extent of my knowledge of ionic.

I looked up the file structure, it all looks the same to me. The only difference I could find was the template structure and rooting is a little bit different. The rest I find the same. My question is, any chance that I could turn my web application into an ionic 3 app? Or do I have to create a new project separately and copy paste all the files that should be the same?

What I really want to do is to have a web and mobile application side by side, and do something (possibly a magic) so that the server knows which files to serve. If the request is being made through a web application, then serve angular template/route otherwise ionic template/route.

P.S. As you can tell, I have no knowledge of ionic yet. Wouldn't call myself an angular expert either. Any help on how to get started would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Any chance that I could turn my web application into an ionic 3 app?* **You can't**

*Or do I have to create a new project separately and copy paste all the files that should be the same?* **No.You need to maintain 2 projects.But you can use most of your Angular components inside the Ionic 3 app.**

You know that `Angular` has very advance routing system.But `Ionic 3` has a sub set of it.That is the key issue here.The other very important difference is the `Angular` version where `Ionic 3` has used.The current stable `Angular` version is `4.3.3`.But unfortunately, `Ionic 3` still uses an older version of `Angular` `4.1.3`.That means you cannot use most of the latest modules where it has been introduced on `Angular 4.3.3` with the `Ionic 3`.

But the Great news is, the Ionic team is working on `Ionic 4` and will release it for `beta` testing soon.Hope that version will eliminate most of the routing issues which are currently on `Ionic 3` and will introduce much more awesome features soon.But you have to wait few more months surely.

[**Ionic 4 is here**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/v4).

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the complexity of your project. If it is simple then there sould be no problem.

- You should be able to reuse all the components
- The html would need to be adapted to the ionic components if you wanted the mobile look
- The routing would have to accomodate the Ionic stuff.